# Index of image subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by a linear transform

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, linear-transformations

The image of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by a linear transform given in canonical basis by $T = \begin{bmatrix}1&-3\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ of index:

Answer: 5.

How do I do this? For what I searched, $\rm{ind}(T)=\rm{dimKer}T - \rm{dimCok}T$, but by gaussian elimination I have that $\rm{Ker}T=\{0\}$, so this difference can't be 5.I think index of linear transform is different than index of image as a subgroup. But then I'm really lost, allI know that may help is Lagrange theorem..

Thanks.

Comment: Subtracting the first row from the second gives $\pmatrix{1 & -3\\0&5}$..

Comment: Think about this question: The image of $\mathbb{Z}$ by the linear transform given by $T(n)=5\cdot n$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ of index 5

Comment: @Sheve, that I can see, because there are 5 classes. But how do I analyze Z^2? Do I have to look at the determinant?

Comment: There are several posts on generalizations of this question, such as: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317065/question-on-determinants-of-matrices-changing-between-integer-matrices), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834431/quotient-group-mathbb-zn-textima), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65913/why-is-the-determinant-equal-to-the-index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case try and look at point not in the image, we have here that a point $(c,d)$ is the image of $(a,b)$ iff $T(a,b)=(c,d)$ this leads us the the equation $c+5b=d$ i.e. $c\sim d$ mod$_5$.

So we obtain that $(c,d)$ is in Im($T$) iff $c\sim d$ mod$_5$.

This leads us to co-sets $(0,i)$ for $i\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ obviously $(0,i) \nsim (0,j)$ for $i\ne j$ and any $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ is conjugate to one of then since $(0,b)\sim (i_a,i_b)\sim (0,i_a-i_b)$  where $i_a+5k=a$